# Word/phrase for mindfulness of health and nutrition?

Tags: phrases

I'm trying to explain that in the summer months, when there may be an inclination to hit the beach and exercise outside, some people may be more careful about what they eat and try to reignite their workout habits.

So is there a word or phrase that captures this healthful focus/mindset?

Comment: Spring fever maybe.

Comment: If you were truly not mindful of your health or nutrition, you'd be dead. So I think the correct word here is "alive"

Answer (score 2):

The term is simply [health-conscious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/health-conscious).

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is "go (or *get*) on a [spring health kick](http://www.blog4safety.com/2012/05/top-five-tips-for-a-spring-health-kick-guest-post/) (or [spree](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spree))."

> [i know people who have gone vegetarian based on health reasons, some for a seasonal health kick or cleanse, and have heard that some even go that route because it is the in thinking](http://www.askejean.com/advicevixens/index.php?topic_id=22225&s=10&order=last_update)

Answer (score 0):

I often use the phrase health-conscious.

From http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/health-conscious

Health-conscious: Describing an attitude in which one has a awareness of the healthiness of one's diet and lifestyle.

More extreme versions would be a health-freak or health-fanatic though they have a bit of a negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting issue; some people seem to care about their shape only when the hot weather  make them dress lighter or take off their clothes when they go to the beach. In my opinion this behaviour has little to do with consciousness about health or well-being. It is more a question of external look to appear in shape or even  sexy. Heath-consciousness is an all year-round issue, not a seasonal one.

Coming to your question I'd call this attitude sort of "look-sensitive" behaviour, something close to fashion trends.

Comment: I would say people are more motivated for those factors but I wouldn't call it just a look-sensitive behaviour. A lot of us know what is good for us when it comes to health but the added benefit of looking good at the beach or having summer clothes look good on us, can help get us to do better at working out and eating healthy. Whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

source - oxford

valetudinarianism - the condition or state of mind of a valetudinarian.

valetudinarian - A person who is unduly anxious about their health